# Scala- operator overloading for an Int

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I was wandering if there is an option to overload the `Int` plus.
just for example, lets say that I want `1+2` to return `1*2`.
can I do something like this?

Comment: Do you mean changing the behavior of `Int` or creating your own integer class where `+`, `-` etc. are overloaded?

Comment: changing the behavior of Int, or if it is not possible, do to it in my own class

Comment: You would have to make your own class. You can't change what `Int`'s `+` method does.

Comment: Ok, but in my own class can I just change one of the oprations of Int?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot overload the methods of a final class such as `Int`. You can only add new (extension) methods:

```
implicit class IntPlusPlus(private val a: Int) extends AnyVal {
  def ++ (b: Int): Int = a * b
}

assert(2 ++ 3 == 6)
```

Or if you want to use `+` for something different, introduce a different type:

```
class MyInt(val self: Int) extends Proxy {
  def + (b: MyInt): MyInt = new MyInt(self * b.self)
}

assert(new MyInt(2) + new MyInt(3) == new MyInt(6))
```

Comment: What's your reason for using `extends AnyVal`?

Comment: That is called a value class and means you will avoid the overhead of actually creating an instance, so you can create extension methods with very little performance cost